# Comparing dates grabbed from an API to todays date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

I'm currently in the process of showing "fixtures" of a sports team on a website, but with all the data grabbed from another website.

I have an API which gets all the data including next opponent, the date of, the kick of time etc.

I'm posting each fixture into a list, and then each element into a different div.

E.g. Each fixture - `<li><div>Date of Fixture</div> <div>Kick off time</div> <div>Home Team</div> <div>Away Team</div></li>`

I have each date in the div:first on each list item, and I have the current date in a span.

I've tried using Date.js to structure the date given, and todays date, into a comparable format, and then to compare them against each other and show the latest one - but I cannot seem to do this with more than one list item.

I want to add a "hidden" class to each list item before todays date.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php
$request = "https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/csv/9shgt89o?apikey=-----";
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$results = json_decode($response);
$currentdate = date("D d M y");
echo "<ul>\n\n";
$f = fopen("https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/csv/9shgt89o?apikey=-----", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
     echo "<li>";
     foreach ($line as $cell) {
         echo "<div>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</div>";
     }
     echo "</li>\n";
     }
fclose($f);
echo "\n</ul>";
echo "<span>" . $currentdate . "</span>"
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="date.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
}

ul li div {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:6px;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
}

ul li {
    padding:6px;
}
</style>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass('hidden');
    $('ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('hidden');
    $('ul li div:nth-child(7)').addClass('hidden');
    $('ul li div:nth-child(8)').addClass('hidden');
    $('span').addClass('date');
});
var todaytext = $('span').text();
var today = Date.parse(todaytext);
document.write('<p>' + today +'</p>');

$('ul li').each(function() {
    Date.parse(this);
});
var fixturetext = $('ul li:eq( div:first').text();
var fixture = Date.parse(fixturetext);
document.write('<p>' + fixture +'</p>');


</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't think I'm far off the answer but I'm just stumbling over myself at the moment!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have *echo* statements before your <!DOCTYPE..> declaration. The doctype should be the first thing in any HTML document.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi David - that's not a problem for now, this is just a testing document to make sure the functions work - this won't be going active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things that should happen to multiple list items should go in the loop. Something like this:

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
    var d = Date.parse(this);
    if( d < today )
        this.hide();
});
```

The PHP statements should go in the HTML body.

Comment: I was parsing the date in the div of the list, but apparently strotime works fine, so this was unnecessary!! Thanks for the help, though.